# Firefox Browser (Ubuntu) converting all my downloads to /tmp/ files

Tags: firefox, downloads, tmp

Whenever I try to download a file (I'm downloading YouTube videos for video editing), instead of appearing in my **Downloads** folder, the file is sent to **/tmp/**, which means I cannot use it for editing and the file is soon unusable.

How can I convert my Firefox browser to put my downloads in the **Downloads** folder?

Comment: Have you checked the preference of firefox in General Tab?

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox there is **Preferences** under menu tab. Go to there and check to which folder go the downloaded files.

Is this your problem? Does it happed only for video files or for every downloaded file?

[image: Firefox preferences]

Comment: It is strange because sometimes my files download normally, whereas video files tend to only download as temporary files. I want to download videos permanently onto my drive.

Comment: Just for a try whenever you download video , just check radio button as "Always ask me where to save file" as I have shown in screen-shot.